# Replace URL for Cfchart in subdomain

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfchart

I have a little problem with `<cfchart>` ...
`<cfchart>` is working fine with my live site.
But, not working with the subdomain.
As, it takes the url for `<cfchart>` as **http://subdomain.mysite.com/CFIDE/GraphChart.cfm**
instead of **http://mysite.com/CFIDE/GraphChart.cfm**

Here is the relevant code:

```
<cfchart format="flash" xaxistitle="Month" yaxistitle="Reviews" chartwidth="180" chartheight="150" show3d="yes">
    <cfchartseries type="bar" colorlist="##778899,##778899,##778899,##778899">
        <cfchartdata item="#DateFormat(LastMonthThree, 'mmm')#" value="0">
    </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

Comment: @Matt Busche : 
Following is my code :

<cfchart format="flash" 
    xaxistitle="Month" 
    yaxistitle="Reviews" chartwidth="180" chartheight="150" show3d="yes">
    <cfchartseries type="bar" colorlist="##778899,##778899,##778899,##778899">
            <cfchartdata item="#DateFormat(LastMonthThree, 'mmm')#" value="0">
    </cfchartseries>

</cfchart>

This is my code.
Actually the problem goes with the subdomain.
The ajax call should be for : http://mysite.com/CFIDE/GraphChart.cfm
but it is http://subdomain.mysite.com/CFIDE/GraphChart.cfm

any idea???

Comment: where are you doing an ajax call?

Comment: @Matt Busche :
Thanks for you reply.
What i know about cfchart is that, it itself do an ajax call.
When we use cfchart, coldfusion itself do an ajax call for /cfide/chartDatat.cfm
So, it works fine for live site as [link](http:mysiste.com/cfide/chartData.cfm)
 But, for mysubdomain (which is actually a subdirectory), the ajax call path is [link] (http://subdomain.mysite.com/cfide/chartData.cfm)
 As, this ajax call is not done by me, so i am unable to change its path.
 Also, i am trying to do something with .htaccess file but it is no t working for subdomain :(
Please help me...

Comment: How are you referencing your subdomain page in the browser?  Is it, http://subdomain.mysite.com or http://mysite.com/subdomain?

Comment: @Miguel-F...thanks for your response...
i am referencing my subdomain as subdomain.mysite.com...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone for responding me...
Anyway, i have solved the problem...
The problem was actually with cfchart-tag which takes map via the relative path to the CFIDE.

```
(/CFIDE/chartData.cfm)
```

So, when i was trying with subdomain.mysite.com, it does find the CFIDE.
`(as it was tring to access **(subdomain.mysite.com/CFIDE/chartData.cfm)`**...
But when i try to access CFIDE with mysite.com/CFIDE, it was working

```
(as it was added from the IIS-Server)
```

So, i just go to the IIS-Manager and add my CFIDE folder to subdomain.mysite.com

```
(subdomain.mysite.com/CFIDE)
```

And it worked...:)